# list to array with different columns in one row python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I need to convert a list to array. But the function asarray does not generate the desired result, do you know how to do the conversion? Thanks!

list:

```
[[1,2],[4,5,6]]
```

convert to array:

```
[[1,2,""],
[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: You need to give more detail.  It's really not obvious what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can use `import numpy` and `numpy.array(<name of list>)` but it won't add zeros if the rows have different sizes.

Answer (score 3):

The desired NumPy array would have to be of dtype `object`. Such arrays enjoy none of the speed advantages of NumPy arrays with native dtypes. You may want to re-adjust your goal.

However, more in the spirit of play than practicality, here is how you *could* create the desired array:

```
In [50]: import itertools as IT

In [51]: seq = [[1,2],[4,5,6]]

In [52]: np.array(zip(*(IT.izip_longest(*seq, fillvalue=''))), dtype='O')
Out[52]: 
array([[1, 2, ''],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
```

(Thanks to @m.wasowski, for the `zip` instead of `list(IT.izip(...))` improvement.)

@utdemir's idea of using -1 as a placeholder would allow you to make a numpy array of native `int` dtype. Using the code above, all you would need to change is the `fillvalue` to `-1`:

```
In [56]: np.array(zip(*(IT.izip_longest(*seq, fillvalue=-1))))
Out[56]: 
array([[ 1,  2, -1],
       [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

Another option would be to use a [NumPy masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html):

```
In [68]: np.ma.masked_less(zip(*(IT.izip_longest(*seq, fillvalue=-1))), 0)
Out[68]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 2 --]
 [4 5 6]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True]
 [False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The masked array would allow you to perform NumPy calculations while correctly handling missing data. For example, the average of the columns could be found this way:

```
In [71]: print(arr.mean(axis=0))
[2.5 3.5 6.0]
```

Notice the average of the last column is 6, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like you should do manually.

```
>>> s = [[1,2], [4,5,6]]
>>> maxl = max(map(len, s))
>>> np.asarray([i + [-1]*(maxl-len(i)) for i in s])
array([[ 1,  2, -1],
       [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

But numpy's arrays are homogenuous, so you can't have both string and int's in array; so I used -1 as placeholder.